# Perl '-d' operator is not detecting a directory

Tags: perl

I am piping the output of some commands to perl. The output consists of a set of filenames and directories, and I want perl to filter out the ones that are directories. Something like this:

```
...some commands... | perl -ne 'print $_ unless -d($_);'
```

The thing is, it is not filtering the directories! For example, output is something like:

```
test/unit_test/ipc
test/unit_test/ipc/tc1.cpp
```

`test/unit_test/ipc` is a directory, but it is still output.

Answer (score 4):

The values of `$_` which are read in by the perl one-liner **include** a trailing newline. Therefore, -d does not even find the directory, let alone recognize that it is a directory.

Here is a solution:

```
...some commands... | perl -ne 'chomp $_; print "$_\n" unless -d $_ ;'
```

Note the use of `chomp` to remove the trailing newline.

---

In conjunction with `-n` or `-p`, `-l` not only adds a newline to `print`ed strings, it `chomp`s the input. That means your code can be simplified to

```
...some commands... | perl -nle 'print $_ unless -d $_;'
```

or even

```
...some commands... | perl -nle'print if !-d'
```

Comment: and in this circumstance, -d will return undef rather than false or true, and you can then know to check $! for an error message

Comment: Maybe be useful to note - by default `chomp` acts on $_ anyway.